# Show ruby core and standard documentation when running gem server

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

Is there a way to show the ruby core and standard library documentation when running `gem server`?

I can navigate the core & std documentation created with rvm, but I would like to have all the documentation in one place.

I've run `rvm docs [generate|generate-ri|generate-rdoc]`, but none of these commands added the documentation in rubygems.

Comment: Have you tried [Yard](http://yardoc.org/)? You can point it to any of your rvm folders and it will create a single documentation for core, stdlib and all the gems you installed via rvm.